# how appbar title calibrate to center in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have `AppBar title` wrap with Row and want to be in center

```
appBar: AppBar(
        title: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Lottie.asset(
              'assets/lottie/coin.json',
              width: 50,
            ),
            const Text('1000'),
          ],
        ),
        centerTitle: true,
        actions: <Widget>[
          Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 20.0),
              child: GestureDetector(
                onTap: () {
                  // _showConfirmationDialog(pageContext);
                },
                child: const Icon(
                  Icons.chat_bubble_outline,
                  size: 26.0,
                ),
              )),
        ],
      ),
```

but seems like its not in center

[image]

there is extra space on left side

[image]

how to calibrate it to center

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting `mainAxisSize` to `MainAxisSize.min`, so that the contents of row will occupy the minimum width needed:

```
title: Row(
    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
```

And I think you don't need `centerTitle: true`, try without it.

Comment: It's probably better to leave `centerTitle: true` there so it works on more platforms.